# How do I rotate an image 45 degrees clockwise manually in python without using scipy library functions?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, transformation

I am working with image data as 28*28 numpy arrays. I have managed to write  functions that flip image data arrays 90 degrees clockwise and anti-clockwise.
I am trying to practice both my knowledge of Linear Algebra and Matrices and my learning of the Numpy Stack. Thus, I do not want to use in-built library functions that directly and automatically transform the image 45degrees clockwise. Instead I am trying to write a function that does the transformation. What am I doing wrong ?

Below is my thought train and trial.

```
# My particular transformation should transform
# the 2*2 Identity Matrix I = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]) to 
# the matrix Iprime = np.array([[1, -1], [-1, 1])
# My function should transform an image input the same way

def Flip45degClockwise(image):
    H, W = image.shape
    res = np.zeros((W, H))

    for i in range(H):
        for j in range(W):
            res[i, j] = image[i, W-j-1] + image[i, j]
    return res
```

Comment: You need a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: Yes the rotation matrix or transformation matrix and then do matrix multiplication with image input. I guess the issue now becomes how to compute the transformation matrix especially depending on the shape of the input image data

Comment: oh ok . I think I understand